# how do i make sprite "igirl" move randomly

Tags: python, pygame

The code inside the update function for "Igirl" does nothing and I'm not sure why, also not sure if the rest of the code is needed to help find a solution.
I've tried putting the random movement code inside the while loop but that causes the sprite to only move up+right/down+right and then get stuck
I've tried using if statements to determine if the sprite has hit the wall to bounce off/keeping heading in that direction.
I've also tried using pygame sprite collide to have it bounce of a border sprite.

None of these work what should i do?

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()
res = (1000, 600)
pygame.display.set_caption("placeholder")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(res)
worldbg = pygame.image.load("worldbg.png").convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Igirl(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.x_speed = 0.2
        self.y_speed = 0.2
        self.direction = 1
        self.frame = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False

        self.sprites.append(ib)

        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]

    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating = True

    def update(self):

        if self.x <= 10 or self.x >= 980:
            self.direction *= -1
            self.x_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.direction
            self.y_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.direction

            if self.x_speed == 0 and self.y_speed == 0:
                self.x_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.direction
                self.y_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.direction

        if self.y <= 600 or self.y >= 10:
            self.direction *= -1
            self.x_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.direction
            self.y_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.direction

            if self.x_speed == 0 and self.y_speed == 0:
                self.x_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.direction
                self.y_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.direction

        self.x += self.x_speed
        self.y += self.y_speed

        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


igirl = Igirl(0, 0)
igirl_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
igirl_sprites.add(igirl)
igirl.rect.x = random.randint(0, 1000)
igirl.rect.y = random.randint(0, 600)
igirl.list = pygame.sprite.Group()
igirl.list.add(igirl)




run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
 
    igirl.animate()

    igirl_sprites.draw(screen)
    igirl_sprites.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.blit(worldbg, (0, 0))
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. How should it move randomly? When should it change direction?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update method, it may be a good idea to track both x and y directions as an attribute in init method of your Igirl class.

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x_direction = 1
    self.y_direction = 1
```

Then change the movement restrictions in update method of your Igirl class since your code does not "bounce" the object off the screen edges. Most importantly, update the `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` attributes which defines the location of the object when drawn to the screen.

```
def update(self):

    if self.x <= 10:
        self.x_direction = 1
    elif self.x >= 980:
        self.x_direction = -1
    else:
        self.x_direction = random.choice([-1, 1])

    if self.y >= 600:
        self.y_direction = -1
    elif self.y <= 10:
        self.y_direction = 1
    else:
        self.y_direction = random.choice([-1, 1])

    self.x_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.x_direction
    self.y_speed = random.randint(0, 8) * self.y_direction
    if self.x_speed == 0 and self.y_speed == 0:
        self.x_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.x_direction
        self.y_speed = random.randint(2, 8) * self.y_direction

    self.x += self.x_speed
    self.y += self.y_speed
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y

    self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())
```